# smtpd_client_restrictions : difference between main.cf and master.cf

Tags: postfix-mta

Where should the `smtpd_client_restrictions` be put: in `main.cf` or in `master.cf` ?

For me, only the `master.cf` seems to be working (because my postfix is  working fine as a relay) :

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission                          
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt                        
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes                              
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated
```

in `main.cf` the following `reject` rule is not applied:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to comment the line in master.cf for client restrictions in submission.  Submission is for linux CLI users on the same machine.  The client restrictions you're trying to use (permit_mynetworks, reject) will only work if the client connects to the smtp ports.  An example of a working client restrictions statement in main.cf is like below on my mail relay in the cloud.

`smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org, reject_rbl_client hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.2, permit`

Answer (score 1):

From what I can recall (someone more knowledgeable can confirm/deny) main.cf restrictions will be by default applied to all smtp processes (so if you have submission/smtps/smtp), but are overwritten by configurations on the actual process (master.cf)

Therefore I'd assume your main.cf value (with reject) is being overwritten by your value on the process (no reject) thus not getting rejected.